# Custom helper for generating html tags for radio button and associated label

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was searching for a solution about radio buttons and associated labels. I like the way we can select each radio button by clicking on the label associated. By default, this doesn't work very well. I mean the labels are not correctly associated with radio buttons.

**Example:** let's say we have a property named Revoked with possible values Yes/No. We would like to use radio buttons to let the user choose the value.

**The problem:** when html tags are generated from MVC (Html.LabelFor, Html.RadioButtonFor), the ID of both radio buttons (Yes/No) are the same. Thus it is impossible to associate each label with the corresponding radio button.

**The solution:** I created my own custom helper for generating html tags with correct and unique ID.

Here is my helper:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonWithLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object value, object labelText)
    {
        object currentValue = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model;
        string property = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).PropertyName;

        // Build the radio button html tag
        TagBuilder htmlRadio = new TagBuilder("input");
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("id", property + value);
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("name", property);
        htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("value", (string)value);

        if (currentValue != null && value.ToString() == currentValue.ToString()) htmlRadio.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

        // Build the label html tag
        TagBuilder htmlLabel = new TagBuilder("label");
        htmlLabel.MergeAttribute("for", property + value);
        htmlLabel.SetInnerText((string)labelText);

        // Return the concatenation of both tags
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlRadio.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + htmlLabel.ToString());
    }
```

It works but I need advise. What do you think? Is it efficient? I'm still new to the world of ASP.NET MVC so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than some minor improvements that could be made the helper looks fine:

- You don't need to call `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` twice with the same arguments
- In order to generate the id you are concatenating the property name with the value but this value could contain any characters while an id in HTML allows only certain characters. You need to sanitize it.
- You are casting both the value and currentValue to strings which might fail if the helper is used on some other property type. In this case either make the helper work only with string properties by reflecting on the helper signature or use `Convert.ToString()`.

Here's the refactored version which takes into account those remarks:

```
public static IHtmlString RadioButtonWithLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
    TProperty value, 
    string labelText
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    object currentValue = metadata.Model;
    string property = metadata.PropertyName;

    // Build the radio button html tag
    var htmlRadio = new TagBuilder("input");
    htmlRadio.GenerateId(property + value);
    htmlRadio.Attributes["type"] = "radio";
    htmlRadio.Attributes["name"] = property;
    htmlRadio.Attributes["value"] = Convert.ToString(value);

    if (object.Equals(currentValue, value))
    {
        htmlRadio.Attributes["checked"] = "checked";
    }

    // Build the label html tag
    var label = new TagBuilder("label");
    label.Attributes["for"] = htmlRadio.Attributes["id"];
    label.SetInnerText(labelText);

    // Return the concatenation of both tags
    return new HtmlString(
        htmlRadio.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + label.ToString()
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This version is much more efficient. I have one question about replacing MvcHtmlString with IHtmlString. What is the difference?

Comment: @Bronzato, both `MvcHtmlString` and `HtmlString` classes implement the `IHtmlString` interface. It is good practice to always expose the highest possible class/interface in the hierarchy in your methods. In this particular case the `MvcHtmlString` was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 2 for backwards compatibility with versions of the .NET framework prior to ASP.NET 4.0. In ASP.NET MVC 3 there's no more reason to use it since it requires ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Hello I used your code..May you help with the razor syntax?thank you

Comment: Is it possible to give an example how to use the custom helper in razor page? @DarinDimitrov