# ASP.NET MVC RadioButtonListFor is always preset

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a radiobuttonlistFor custom adapter working, but if a users form data is reset, and no data has been previously submitted, one of the radio buttons (the first) is always preselected, I want to avoid this, how can I achieve this?

```
@Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(model => model.ViewModelForThingCreate.ThingTypeID, Model.ViewModelForCarCreate.CarTypeSelectList)
```

and:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> HTMLHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> Expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfValues)
        {
            var MetaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Expression, HTMLHelper.ViewData);
            var SB = new StringBuilder();

            if (ListOfValues != null)
            {
                foreach (SelectListItem Item in ListOfValues)
                {
                    var ID = string.Format("{0}_{1}", MetaData.PropertyName, Item.Value);
                    var Radio = HTMLHelper.RadioButtonFor(Expression, Item.Value, new { id = ID }).ToHtmlString();
                    SB.AppendFormat("<label class=\"radio inline\" for=\"{0}\">{1} {2}</label>", ID, Radio, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Item.Text));
                }
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(SB.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: how do you feel about using js?

Comment: That's always the last resort...

Comment: check out this slick radio button helper from Darin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553408/custom-helper-for-generating-html-tags-for-radio-button-and-associated-label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried your method in mvc3 template and it seems to work fine for me. Basically I've created some Model

```
 public class IndexModel
 {
     public string ID;
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Elements;
 }
```

Then created instance and filled values:

```
var model = new IndexModel()
            {
                ID = "a",
                Elements = 
                       new List<SelectListItem>() { 
                                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "test1", Value = "1"},
                                                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "test2", Value = "2"}}
            };
```

In view I've used your extension method

```
<form>
@(Extensions.RadioButtonForSelectList(Html, x => x.ID, Model.Elements))
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

All seem perfectly fine after launch. Fields are not selected at load and they're cleared after pressing "Reset" button.

[image]

Can you give some more details as I'm not sure if I fully understand what are you trying to achieve :-)

**EDIT:**

Here's example in plain HTML of radio buttons. They're definitely not filled at the beginning and if you want them to be required add **required** but by default you can send form without selecting any radio button. Also you can make one checked by adding checked as in second example. Are you using some javascript on client side? Maybe it is causing this side-effect?  http://jsbin.com/isadun/1

mz

Answer (score 2):

This is your custom helper with the buttons set to not checked. Try this, I assume it will render all radio buttons unchecked.

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> HTMLHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> Expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfValues)
        {
            var MetaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Expression, HTMLHelper.ViewData);
            var SB = new StringBuilder();

            if (ListOfValues != null)
            {
                foreach (SelectListItem Item in ListOfValues)
                {
                    var ID = string.Format("{0}_{1}", MetaData.PropertyName, Item.Value);
                    var Radio = HTMLHelper.RadioButtonFor(Expression, Item.Value, new { id = ID }).ToHtmlString();
                    SB.AppendFormat("<label class=\"radio inline\" checked="false" for=\"{0}\">{1} {2}</label>", ID, Radio, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Item.Text));
                }
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(SB.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Damn! Leme think about another approach

Comment: @Baconbeastnz, the only other thing i can think of is JS. But ow that feels wrong

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately One radio button must always be checked. That is the unfortunate part about radio buttons; however, You could always add a hidden radio button to your form and set the checked property to true; Have your internal code accept a null or whatever you expect if nothing is selected from it.

Try Setting all of the radio buttons value's to unchecked or false

```
foreach(button in ButtonGroup){
button.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: one radio button must always be checked? That can't be correct, surely?

Comment: Radio buttons require one to be true because they are used to force the user to select one of the selections. If you used checkboxes and had JS code that disabled the other boxes when one is selected then you could have all of them marked as false. If you need to have one not selected then that might be a better implementation.

Comment: I'm talking about initial state. I'm sure you can have them unselected intially.Anyway

Comment: Right, that's what I am telling you. There is always one radio button selected in a group by default. If you do not set one to be true then the first one in the list will always be selected first.

Comment: Look below, this is false.